# Scroll to position of page on click jquery & html

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have just changed my website to be dynamic switching from html to php for a lot of my pages. In doing so I have lost a scroll effect I was using in jquery. The function allowed the user to click on the appropriate link on the header and it would scroll to the class linked to that button. In making the page dynamic each div on the page now has the same id. I was wondering if there was a way to set the buttons to scroll to specific pixels, or potentially using nth child?

```
function ScrollTo(id, speed)
{
$('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(id).offset().top
    }, speed);

    return false;
}


<div class="header-case2">
        <a class="case2" onclick="ScrollTo('.case-div-1', 599)">Technology</a>
        <a class="case2" onclick="ScrollTo('.case-div-2', 599)">Local Authority     Modules</a>
        <a class="case2" onclick="ScrollTo('.case-div-3', 599)">Data Channel</a>
        <a class="case2" onclick="ScrollTo('.case-div-8', 599)">Housing     Solutions</a>
        <a class="case2" onclick="ScrollTo('.case-div-4', 599)"> Tenant     Engagement</a>
        <a class="case2" onclick="ScrollTo('.case-div-6', 599)">H&A Management</    a>
       </div>


$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM solutions');
$results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

for ($i=0; $i < count($results); $i++) {

  echo '<div class="case-div">';
  echo '<h2 class="upper-blue">'.$results[$i]['headline'].'<br>'.'</h2>';
  echo '<p class="pp13">'.$results[$i]['text'].'<br>'.'</p>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '<div class="pa7"></div>';
}
```

Comment: echo '<div class="case-div-'.$i.'">';

Comment: or maybe echo '<div class="case-div-'.$i+1.'">';

Comment: @Stender So if I add : .$i. this will auto increment each div?

Comment: $i is the index of your array - starting on 0

Comment: okay I will try this out. Thank you for the help!

Comment: yes this worked! thank you

Comment: no problem mate - I will post an answer so you can accept

Comment: To motivate people on SO to help the community and answer questions, it is a nice gesture to accept answers. But it is of course your choice if you choose to do so. But doing so, shows that the question is closed to the other users, and they will not have to go in here in vain.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your increments on your divs -

this can be easily fixed by adding your $i (your index of the for loop) so your divs classes -

```
echo '<div class="case-div-'.$i.'">';
```

Or maybe

```
echo '<div class="case-div-'.$i+1.'">';
```

since it starts on zero - This will make your onclicks work again.